# Firebase: How do I limit number of child objects in a query for its parent?

Tags: angularjs, firebase

In my Firebase I have a users collection in which each user has a child "posts" that contains multiple posts (like Facebook).  On each user page I load the posts all in one query for the user object.  However over time the number of posts will become very large.

1. What is the "right" way to limit the number of posts that come without making a separate call (or is that the only way)?  I plan to implement infinite scroll.
2. Generally speaking is it bad practice to make multiple calls with an Angular/Firebase stack?  Can someone direct me to a "best practices" resource?

Thanks a lot for your help!

### Edit

For the user collection it looks thus

```
users : { 
  user1 : { posts : [<post>], username : <username> ... }, 
  user2 : { posts : [<post>], username : <username> ... }, 
  ... 
}
```

Comment: Your code will help use to understand more. PLease share

Comment: For the user collection it looks thus - 

users : { 
  user1 : {  posts : [<post>], username : <username> ... },
  user2 : {  posts : [<post>], username : <username> ... },
...
}

Comment: I added the data structure you included in the comment. But that is not code. Please *edit* your question to include the code that does "on each user page I load the posts all in one query for the user object".

Answer (score 1):

You can limit the number of items you take using the [limitToFirst](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limittofirst.html) and [limitToLast](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/limittolast.html) functions.

To implement pagination, though, you'll might want to use [startAt](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/startat.html) and [endAt](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/api/query/endat.html).  You would combine it with once to only get the paginated data once.

In fact, Firebase has an [example of pagination](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2013-10-01-queries-part-one.html#paginate) using startAt, limitToFirst and once.